# Erro ao abrir o eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Depois que reinstalei ubuntu no meu notebook, ao tentar abrir o eclipse aparece o seguinte erro:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/joao/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/joao/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/joao/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
/home/joao/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
-startup    
/home/joao/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2d0009
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/joao/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Comment: +1 Aconteceu comigo isso também há umas duas semanas atrás. No entanto, eu não soube como resolver. :(

Comment: Você usa o Ubuntu 64 ou 32 bits? Tem instalado o `OpenJDK`?

Comment: Uso o ubuntu 64 bits e tenho o jdk instalado

Comment: Qual versão JDK você usa e qual do Java? Ali ele está pedindo a 1.6 (-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6)

Comment: java version "1.9.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.9.0-ea-b54)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.9.0-ea-b54, mixed mode)

Comment: @JoãoCarlos, experimente instalar a JDK da Oracle no Ubuntu e testar novamente: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html